# How does Pix's damage work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Lulu's passive, Pix, provides extra attacks for herself or an ally, depending on who Pix is currently following.

What does this damage scale from? Does it scale with AD, AP, etc.? Is Pix's damage Magical or Physical? Does Pix attack when the ally uses spells, or just for autoattacks?

Comment: It is a little hard to tell what you are asking here.

Comment: Michael Ayres, I understand that English is not your first language, but many of your posts are incomprehensible at first. Please take the time to re-read and revise your posts before posting to help out everyone. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer can (hopefully) be found here: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress

Comment: @StrixVaria it's Michel not Michael =) and i read twice, and for me was ok. going to re-check and vote to re-open it

Comment: @MichelAyres I specifically tried to type it without the A, but since my name is "Michael", it was automatic for me to include it :( Sorry about that.

Comment: no Problem =) btw, I made some changes, take a look.

Comment: @Toast Sorry it does not answer my question. It does not said if I bought one AD item, Pix will deal more damage with this or if I bought one AP item, Pix will deal more damage with this. Also, it does not said in what is based the damage when I use Help pix in someone else

Comment: @StrixVaria WOW. That was a improvement in the question o.O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the answers to this question(s) one-by-one:

**What does [Pix's] damage scale from?**

Pix's damage scales with Lulu's level. The formula for Pix's damage is:

> Pix fires a barrage of 3 bolts, dealing 3 + (2 × level) magic damage each

**Does it scale with AD, AP, etc.?**

As you can see from the formula above. it does not scale with Attack damage (AD), Ability Powers (AP) or any other champion stat (Mana, Health, etc.) and is based solely on Lulu's level.

**Is Pix's damage Magical or Physical?**

Pix deals magic damage exclusively. Therefore his damage is dependent on the users Magic Penetration and the targets Magic Resist stats. There is some speculation about whose Magic Penetration Pix uses when making his attacks from an ally (not Lulu) as noted [in this link](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1928198).

**Does Pix attack when the ally uses spells, or just for autoattacks?**

Pix's attack is triggered by autoattacks only. Casting spells that refresh the attack animation (Nasus's Siphoning Strike, Blitz's Power Fist, etc) may provide additional attacks from Pix but to maximize the damage you probably want to target a champion with a higher attack speed.

For more information about Lulu and Pix check out her entry on the [LoL Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress).

Answer (score 5):

According to the [LoL Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress),

***Pix, Faerie Companion*** deals **Magic** damage, and scales with *Level* rather than items.

> Pix fires a barrage of 3 bolts, dealing 3 + (2 × level) magic damage
>   each, at whomever Lulu attacks. These bolts are homing but can be
>   blocked by other units.

Comment: Thus the best way to increase Pix's damage is to use "Help, Pix!" on your AD carry who has increased their Attack Speed - Pix will hit more often!

Answer (score 1):

Pix's damage does not scale with ap or ad, but rather with level and attack speed:

> (Innate): Pix fires a barrage of 3 bolts, dealing 3 + (2 × level)
>   magic damage each, at whomever Lulu attacks. These bolts are homing
>   but can be blocked by other units.

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Lulu_the_Fae_Sorceress)